# Understanding Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

I'm reading through a introductory PDF on SQL and came across the following: "A foreign key in a table is a column (or **group of columns**) which is a primary key in another table."

Would a table having Foreign Keys which **form a group of columns** just be directly related to multiple tables associated with these Foreign Keys?

Also, is it possible for a Table to have multiple Primary Keys? If so, what does this actually mean?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would a table having Foreign Keys which form a group of columns just
>   be directly related to multiple tables associated with these Foreign
>   Keys?

A table having foreign keys can be related (referenced) to multiple tables. Take this example,

```
Table A
--------
Col1 FK references B.Col1
Col2 FK references B.Col2
Col3 FK references C.Col3
...

Table B
--------
Col1 PK <---|
Col2 PK <---| composite primary key

Table C
--------
Col3 PK <--- single primary key
```

In the above case, Table A has foreign keys (col1, Col2, Col3) that are primary keys for other tables (B and C). Note here, Table B's primary key is a composite primary key with 2 columns. Hence you need to refer both of them.

> is it possible for a Table to have multiple Primary Keys?

No. But one PK may contain multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why we would ever need a `Composite Primary key'?

Comment: This could very well be the topic for a new question. *Hint*: imagine uniqueness of a student is defined by the combination of both `firstName` and `lastName`

Answer (score 3):

A table having multiple foreign keys will have relationships to the primary keys of multiple tables.

A table with a Foreign key comprised of multiple columns needs to point to a single table with a primary key comprised of the same columns (both meaning and datatype).

You can only have a single primary key per table. It can be comprised of multiple columns, in which case it's a composite primary key.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why we would ever need a `Composite Primary key'?